# Is there a way to print curl GET output in new lines?

Tags: curl

Below is output of my curl -k -X GET -H... command

```
{"status":true,"log":"[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-output is : x  \n[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-Running test in SUPER   \n[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-Test is success !!!  \n[2021-12-05 00:29:50+0000]-Now end .  \n"}
```

Instead of getting output like above , how can i get it like below in the terminal . I tried using -w , it didnt work

```
{"status":true,"log":"
[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-output is : x  
[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-Running test in SUPER   
[2021-12-05 00:28:15+0000]-Test is success !!!  
[2021-12-05 00:29:50+0000]-Now end .  
"}
```

Essentially i am trying to make the output easier for copy paste activities . The output has no limit of number of lines .

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by piping with sed

```
curl -k -X GET -H... |sed 's/\\n/\n/g' |sed 's/\\t/\t/g'
```